# SqlPlus on mac osx 10.6 doesn't work

Tags: sql, macos, oracle10g

When i try to run this

```
#sqlplus system@orcl
```

it gives me this error

```
SQL*Plus: Release 10.1.0.3.0 - Production on Tue Apr 20 02:24:41 2010

Copyright (c) 1982, 2004, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password: 
ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

the oracle server is working , I can connect through SQLDeveloper

My .profile looks like this

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH    
# Setting PATH for Python 3.1
# The orginal version is saved in .profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/bin:${PATH}"
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/lesce/instantclient
export TNS_ADMIN=/Users/lesce/instantclient
export ORACLE_SID="orcl"
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/lesce/instantclient
```

tnsnames.ora

```
    ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

listener.ora

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /Users/oracle/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = orcl)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /Users/oracle/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1)
    )
  )
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC0))
    )
  )
```

My SqlDeveloper configuration

```
username : sys
role : sysdba
connection type : basic
hostname : localhost
port : 1521
sid : orcl
```

Comment: What are the connection parameters you're using in SQL Developer? What are the contents of `TNSNAMES.ORA`?

Comment: I've edited the post with tnsnames.ora , listener.ora and my SqlDeveloper connection config .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete extraneous space in tnsnames.ora before ORCL (shown as underscores for clarity):

_____ORCL =

should be

ORCL =

SQLDeveloper does not use tnsnames.ora in "basic" mode, so it is not affected.

Comment: If it does not help, regenerate the configuration with Net Configuration Assistant.

Comment: It's not the extraneous space , that was just how I pasted it .
I've given up and installed ubuntu in a virtual machine , thanks for the answer .